# How to continue spotlight search and show content ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication, corespotlight

I had get Spotlight search all sorted out, the problem I'm facing now is how to show the content view based on the item which has been press in spotlight.

**My app's structure is `UITabVC`>`UINavigationVC`>`UICollectionVC`>`UIVC`**

---

**spotlight and code is shown below**

```
// Continue Spotlight Search
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {
        let uniqueIdentifier = userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as! String
        let id = uniqueIdentifier.components(separatedBy: "_")
        let rootTabVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootTabVC") as! RootTabVC

        print(id[0], id[1], separator: " - ", terminator: "\n")
        // printed "craft - Shovel"

        switch id[0] {
        case "craft" :
            let craftVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CraftDetailVC") as! CraftItemDetailVC
            let craftRootCollectionVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CraftRootCollectionVC") as! CraftCollectionVC
            let craftItemsCollectionVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CraftItemsCollectionVC") as! CraftItemsCollectionVC
            // MARK: - TODO show vc

        case "character" : break
        case "mob" : break
        case "plant" : break
        case "recipe" : break
        case "thing" : break
        case "material" : break
        default: break
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even I have same problem in my one of the app. Then I was surfing on internet for solution, [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/116608/ios-9-app-search-tutorial-introduction-to-app-search) the best sample example and code along with it's explanation.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
    restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

      guard userActivity.activityType == Employee.domainIdentifier,
        let objectId = userActivity.userInfo?["id"] as? String else {
          return false
      }

      if let nav = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
        let listVC = nav.viewControllers.first as? EmployeeListViewController,
        let employee = EmployeeService().employeeWithObjectId(objectId) {
          nav.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

          let employeeViewController = listVC
            .storyboard?
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmployeeView") as!
          EmployeeViewController

          employeeViewController.employee = employee
          nav.pushViewController(employeeViewController, animated: false)
          return true
      }

      return false
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

In your `ApplicationDelegate` class implement this function:

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {`

Then you can access the clicked `CSSearchableItem`'s  `uniqueIdentifier` by:

`if let searchActivityIdentifier = userActivity.userInfo [CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String {
}`

Then all you need to do is to redirect user to related view controller based on `searchActivityIdentifier`value.(push, present etc.)